# How do you make an image show beside stacked text inside an H1 tag?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the image below to show next to the text. With tables this would be really easy. What's the right way with css? Ideally the text on the left and the image on the right with the text vertically and horizontally centered in it's half of the h1 or div.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R4WGd/) of what I have so far, and below is the html and css as well.

html:

```
<h1>
    <div class="title">
        SonoSmile
    </div>
    <div class="subtitle">
        4D Fetal Imaging
    </div>
    <div class="catchline">
        2D, 3D, and 4D Ultrasound
    </div>
        <img class="logo" src="images/james-michael-3d-ultrasound-smiling-at-25-weeks-pregnancy.jpg" width="250" alt="You don't need an excuse to be happy.">
</h1>
```

css:

```
h1
{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-weight:bolder;
    border:thin;
    border-style:solid;
}



.title
{
    font-size:48px;
}

.subtitle
{
    font-size:30px;     
}

.catchline
{
    font-size:22px;
}
```

Comment: Put the image before the text, and add `float:right` to its CSS. Optionally, add some `margin-left` to space it away a little.

Comment: You really shouldn't be wrapping each text section in a `div` like that unless absolutely necessary. There are a range of appropriate text tags (`p`, `span` `headings` etc) that would probably serve you better. Particulalry don't put block elements inside `h1` tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**JSFIddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4J85Y/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="text">
        <h1 class="title">SonoSmile</h1>
        <h2 class="font-size:30px;  ">4D Fetal Imaging</h2>
        <h3 class="catchline" >2D, 3D, and 4D Ultrasound</h3>

    </div>
    <img class="logo" src="http://sonosmile.com/images/james-michael-3d-ultrasound-smiling-at-25-weeks-pregnancy.jpg" width="250" alt="You don't need an excuse to be happy."/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper 
{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-weight:bolder;
    border:thin;
    border-style:solid;
    overflow:hidden;
} 

.title {
    font-size:48px;
}

.subtitle {
    font-size:30px;     
}

.catchline {
    font-size:22px;
}

.text {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}

.wrapper img.logo {
    display:block;
    float:right;
    width:50%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The only way I knew to do this was tables. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

move the "img" tag outside the "h1" block. add this to css:

```
.logo{float:right; width:250px;}
```

Comment: The text an image kind of need to go together. When I try what you suggest the image goes to the far right, not beside the text. Thanks for such a fast response.

Comment: play with the CSS to move your image where you want it to go. adjusting the 'margin-right' should do it